# Value inside submitted task always the same - ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, blockchain, executorservice

I'm creating a simple blockchain application, I have a method for mining new blocks and a method where I can submit mining tasks.

Here is the method that I use for submitting new tasks using `ExecutorService#submit`:

```java
public void executeCommand(int noOfStartingZero) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_BLOCKS; i++) {
            executor.submit(() -> {
                Block prevBlock = this.blockchain.getBlocks().peekLast();
                Block block = this.minerCommand.mine(prevBlock, noOfStartingZero);
                System.out.println("block: " + block);
                String minedBy = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                block.setMinedBy(minedBy);
                try {
                    this.blockchain.addNewBlock(block);
                } catch (InvalidBlockException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();
 }
```

The problem is, on this line, it always returns the same block:  `Block block = this.minerCommand.mine(prevBlock, noOfStartingZero);`

Here is my `mine()` method, each time it gets called it will create a new block:

```java
 public Block mine(Block prevBlock, int noOfStartingZero) {
        if (prevBlock == null) {
            return getGenesisBlock(noOfStartingZero);
        }
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        var block = new Block();
        block.setId(prevBlock.id() + 1);
        block.setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());
        block.setPrevHash(prevBlock.hash());

        BlockHashContainer hashContainer = generateHash(block, noOfStartingZero);
        block.setMagicNumber(hashContainer.getMagicNumber());
        block.setHash(hashContainer.getHash());
        block.setTimeGenerated((new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000);
        return block;
 }
```

I tried to print out the block for each iteration, and here is what I got, it always returns the first block, and no other block is added to the blockchain:

```java
block: Block[id=1, timestamp=1632128365538, prevHash=0, hash=818b72956bdb163b5b51b848c2988378cb03bd58649511186ac9a5339d9e392c]
block: Block[id=1, timestamp=1632128365538, prevHash=0, hash=818b72956bdb163b5b51b848c2988378cb03bd58649511186ac9a5339d9e392c]
block: Block[id=1, timestamp=1632128365537, prevHash=0, hash=a840f8f7922fae5b974e1a4e286dbd7247ed19efb12629ba8b0533b117c9451d]
block: Block[id=1, timestamp=1632128365538, prevHash=0, hash=818b72956bdb163b5b51b848c2988378cb03bd58649511186ac9a5339d9e392c]
block: Block[id=1, timestamp=1632128365516, prevHash=0, hash=336385001bb8a9f7b16800fd94e09347dac1a2566bd0edfd0ea6c941b722dd4d]
```

Why it behaves like this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you return `getGenesisBlock` for ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `ExecutorService` to run this operation has the potential to run each iteration concurrently. This means that they can all see `prevBlock` as `null` before any task has the opportunity to set it. If each iteration depends on the result of the previous operation, there’s no reason to use an  `ExecutorService` at all. Instead, run each mining operation synchronously within the loop.

Comment: But I still want effectively I can use multiple miners for creating new blocks, what should I change? Thanks.

Comment: Does each block depend on the previous block? If so, I don’t see how this is possible.